# C# Reflexion => PropertyInfo of indexed item of list (like obj1.List<obj3>[0])

Tags: c#, propertyinfo

I made a method for looping on an object and return the PropertyInfo of each of his properties.

It's OK for all, except types of objects who are in a list.

I need to return the PropertyInfo of the first (or next) object in a list;

By example, if i put the parameter "obj1.MyList[0]" to my method, it return the PropertyInfo of obj3 because MyList is a property of type "List".

```
        /// <summary>Récupère les meta-information de la propriétés "pPropertyName".</summary>
    /// <returns>Item1=PropertyInfo, Item2=ObjetParent, Item3=ValeurDeLaPropriété</returns>
    public static Tuple<PropertyInfo, object, object> GetPiByName(object pObj, string pPropertyName) {
        PropertyInfo pi = null;
        object val = pObj;
        object valParent = null;
        Type currentType = val.GetType();
        var idx = -1;
        foreach (string propertyName in pPropertyName.Split('.')) {
            var posi = propertyName.IndexOf('[');
            if ((posi>0) && int.TryParse(propertyName.Substring(posi + 1, propertyName.Length - propertyName.IndexOf(']')), out idx)) {
                pi = currentType.GetProperty(propertyName.Substring(0, posi));
                currentType = pi.PropertyType;
                valParent = val;
                val = pi.GetValue(val, null);
                if ((val is IEnumerable) && (idx >= 0)) { // Pour les listes
                    valParent = val;
                    val = ((IList)val)[idx];
                    currentType = val.GetType();
                    pi = ??? [WHAT DO I PUT FOR RETURN PropertyInfo OF VAL] ???
                    idx = -1;
                    continue;
                } // */
            } else
                pi = currentType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            currentType = pi.PropertyType;
            valParent = val;
            val = pi.GetValue(val, null);
        }
        return new Tuple<PropertyInfo, object, object>(pi, valParent, val);
    }
```

Regards

Comment: Items inside of a List are not Properies and cant have a PropertyInfo.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, If `val` is `IEnumerable` you will have to iterate through it and get the `PropertyInfo` of each item in the list.

Comment: The syntax `obj1.List<obj3>[0]` makes no sense. There can be multiple properties of type `List<obj3>`. Anyway you need to treat collections differently. If you determine `[n]` to be the syntax to return the nth item in a collection, then cast the object to a collection type with an indexer and return the nth item. Worst case, you need to actually enumerate to do that. You also seem to lack recursion (`foo.Foo2.Foo3.ListProp[3]`).

Comment: Hello Ian,
Yes, I thought that too,but i can get the PropertyInfo of Obj1.Obj3 (not in array), i hope that is possible to get the same result with List item.

Comment: Hello Bradley, Val is the value who has be set in property, i can get all values of my List, but no the PropertyInfo of indexed item.

Comment: Hello CodeCaster, indeed, obj1.List<obj3>[0] make no sense, but i think it's speaking and short, who is desired for a title.
The problem is that i can't get the PropertyInfo without the parent property. And in this case, i can't determinate her.
If you have an idea, could you show an exemple, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj1.MyList[0]` does not refer to a property - it refers to the result of evaluating the getter of the indexer property `MyList` with argument `0`.

The syntax `a.prop[0]` is just C# syntax sugar for `a.prop.get_Item(0)` where `get_Item` is a compiler-generated getter method for the indexer property.

What you're trying to achieve is no more valid than asking for the `MethodInfo` of `int.Parse("123")` - you can take the `MethodInfo` of `int.Parse`, but not of `int.Parse("123")`.

Comment: Ok, it's not possible, so.
i have to process this case differently. I will interprate the list and get the type after.
Thanks all for your lights

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you cannot define the 3rd element of a list as being a property.

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

> A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read,
>   write, or compute the value of a private field. Properties can be used
>   as if they are public data members, but they are actually special
>   methods called accessors. This enables data to be accessed easily and
>   still helps promote the safety and flexibility of methods.

Can you explain for what do you need this ?

Comment: it's for automation of a dynamic filter. by type of a property, i want display the adapted control (textbox for a string, combobox for an enum, autocomplete for an object, ...).
and it's possible for user to create a collection for cumulate many filters of same object.
But i need to get the type property type of collection for reuse my automations.